# Returning True or False in Laravel's Tinker

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have few users in my database with job posts. Few have more jobs posted and one user has one job posted.

In my Laravel'5 tinker, to get total jobs posted: `\App\Job::count();`. If I need to see a specific user's job post: `\App\User::find(6)->jobs`. But I can never find a user with x job posts, for example for trying to show a user with one job posted: `\App\User::where('jobs', '==', '1')->first();`. I got those from the Laravel's website but I get an empty array: `[]`. I do have a user with one job post. How can I return users with x job post?

I even tried this: `\App\User::find(9)->jobs == 1` hoping to get true but I get false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Eloquent's [`has`](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#querying-relations) method:

```php
\App\User::has('jobs', '=', '1')->first();
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks. Where you got that "has" from? I have looked all over.